# Процедура не выполняется при каждом вызове события

Tags: delphi

Допустим есть событие OnEvent, которое вызывается каждые 15 милисек. По этому событию выполняеться процедура `proc1(x,y,z,a:integer)`, которая выполняется 100 милисек. В результате, пока не будет обработано предыдущее событие, следующее не выполнится, и множество промежуточных действий (процедур) пропускается.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы процедура добавлялась в очередь и из очереди процедуры последовательно выполнялись? Или есть какое-нибудь другое решение?

Comment: а как Вы себе это представляете? если каждые 15мс должна выполнятся процедура длительностью 100, то где брать время?
ну или поставьте 100/15  = 7 процессоров, должны управиться.

Comment: ну а как сделать так чтобы выполнялась КАЖДАЯ процедура. Общее время выполнения неважно. Главное чтобы выполнилось. Неужели нельзя организоввать очередь?

Comment: По событию создавайте поток, который будет выполнять вашу процедуру, вам придется теперь задуматься о данных, требуемых для процедуры, чтобы они были статичными в пределах одного потока. Возможно придется синхронизировать потоки, если результаты одной процедуры зависят от другой.

Comment: Может быть, вместо 100 мс процедуры исполнять какую-то более короткую, которая, в частности, считает число Событий. А затем, под конец запустить все 100 мс процедуры, которые следовало выполнить. А?
Или создать 7-8 потоков с регулятором :-(

Comment: @BuilderC, логичная альтернатива моему варианту. Придется хранить все данные тогда в списке, например.

Comment: Нужно смотреть на producer-consumer модель. Там как раз эта проблема и решается.
Но нужно понимать, что очередь не безгранична.

Comment: @Dex, конечно придется, но помещение в список - сравнительно быстрая процедура.

Comment: @BuilderC, совершенно согласен и ничего не имею против.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно исполняемый код поместить в отдельный класс и организовать очередь. Один поток будет каждые 15 секунд добавлять новый экземпляр в конец очереди (что не займет много времени). Другой поток должен циклично проверять очередь и брать экземпляры класса из начала очереди для исполнения. Тогда в лучшем случае ваш событийный код будет исполняться раз в 15 секунд, в худшем - никуда не пропадет и выполнится рано или поздно.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод TThread, в частности, [TThread.Queue](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread_Queue@TThread@TThreadMethod.html). Подробнее [многопоточные программы в Delphi изнутри](http://symmetrica.net/Delphi/threads.htm).

Windows API предлагает [пул потоков](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms686980(v=VS.85).aspx), который позволяет подавать задачи на исполнения быстрее, чем они выполняются, в расчете на то, что они выполнятся позднее, когда ресурс освободится (либо выполнение будет происходить на параллельных процессорах).

Comment: Ваша ссылка на многопоточные программы не работает.